# Обмен данными между таблицами в бд

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Как сделать когда в таблицу 'messages' забивается id юзера из таблицы 'members' ,что бы этот id  озночал имя(name) или фамилию(username)  юзера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как-то странно формулируете вопрос. Рискну предположить, что при показе сообщения Вы хотите показать не ИД пользователя, а его имя (фамилию). Тогда это делается таким запросом:

```
select messages.msgtext, members.name from messages inner join members on members.userid=messages.userid;
```

С уважением,

для вызова из php:

```
mysql_query("select messages.msgtext, members.name from messages inner join members on members.userid=messages.userid");
```

пояснения:

1. в SQL имена таблиц и полей не обязательно писать во внутренних кавычках. Обязательно - только в случае когда имя таблицы/поля совпадает с зарезервированным(служебным) словом SQL. Потому написал без...
2. messages - таблица с сообщениями. msgtext - так я назвал поле в таблице messages, в котором находится текст сообщения (просто не знаю Вашего названия). messages.msgtext - это прямое обращение к полю по имени как поля так и таблицы. Такой формат используется, в частности, когда объединяются несколько таблиц в которых есть одинаковые имена полей. В противном случае mysql не может определить поле какой именно таблицы Вы "имеете в виду"...
3. inner join - объединение таблиц по условию, указанному далее после on. on members.userid=messages.userid - условие по которому происходит объединение (т.е. ищутся соответствующие друг другу записи). В данном случае, значение поля userid из таблицы members должно совпадать со значением userid из таблицы messages.

Советую почитать что-либо по SQL/MySQL...

Comment: Добавил пояснения.

Comment: Честно говоря чего то у меня все ровно не чего не получается.

Comment: Если у Вас так ничего и не получилось, конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос - приведите структуру таблиц (по крайней мере ключевые поля), а также, чего конкретно Вы хотите добиться. С конкретикой работать будет легче. С уважением,